# Was Fletcher Reede’s Secretary Greta’s tale of the burglar who cut himself on his victim’s knife and then sued for negligence true?

Tags: negligence

In liar liar Fletcher Reede (Jim Carey)’s Secretary Greta tells a story about a burglar Who enters a home through a sky light and cuts himself on a knife and then sued the homeowner for negligence in leaving the knife out. Was there ever a case like this?

Comment: [Katko v. Briney](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Katko_v._Briney) comes to mind, but of course "hurt by a booby trap set for that explicit purpose" is different from "hurt by grabbing a kitchen knife left on the table".

Comment: The important point is "for negligence". I don't think it would ever be _negligent_ to leave a sharp knife where a burglar can hurt himself. It's either a booby trap, or it's just bad luck for the burglar, but not negligence. I think I'd have to anticipate someone entering my garden shed, or even breaking through the front door of my home, but not entering my home through a sky light.

Comment: @KFK do you think the monologue of Greta was likely to be referring to this case?

Comment: @Seekinganswers I am not going to pay for and watch a 1h30 film for the sole purpose of answering a law.se question. Please give any necessary details in the post.

Comment: Sorry, it’sa classic so I thought you might have already seen it